# Multiple connections with aiosqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, discord.py, python-asyncio

I have a **discord bot** that uses an sqlite db to read/write data to my db using **aiosqlite**

I have written multiple functions to read/write, and **each of these functions establishes a separate connection to the database**.

Example:

```py
import aiosqlite
DATABASE_PATH = "path/to/db"

async def funcOne(DATABASE_PATH,param):

    async with aiosqlite.connect(DATABASE_PATH) as conn:
     async with conn.execute(SQL,param) as cur:
        query_result = await cur.fetchone()
        # do stuff here
        await conn.commit()

async def funcTwo(DATABASE_PATH,):

    async with aiosqlite.connect(DATABASE_PATH) as conn:
     async with conn.execute(SQL,param) as cur:
        query_result = await cur.fetchone()
        # do stuff here
        await conn.commit()
```

then in my bot commands I have:

```py
from discord.ext import commands

@commands.command(name="commandOne")
async def commandOne(ctx,param1):

    # Do stuff
    await funcOne(DATABASE_PATH, param1)

@commands.command(name="commandTwo")
async def commandTwo(ctx,param1):

    # Do stuff
    await funcTwo(DATABASE_PATH, param1)
```

My questions are:

1. Is creating a separate connection each time is a good practice?
2. Can this cause inconsistency in the data ?
3. If the answer to 2. is yes, how can I solve this?

Comment: Is it good practice?  Depends.  It's not the normal practice, and it wastes resources.  It is certainly common to pull multiple cursors from a single connection.  Can it cause consistency problems?  That depends.  Is one of these reading data the other is generating?  The database won't make new data visible until you do the `commit`.  The other side will simply see the original data until you do that.

Comment: What's the normal practice then ?
Create one connection and then use it all accross the bot ? 
Does that one connection lock the db when it's writing data ? 
What should I do here to fix what I have done ? 
Some functions read, some write, and some do both

Comment: Yes, normal practice is to have one long-term database connection, using multiple cursors.  Remember that your backend here is a highly tuned professional database system, engineered for large volume simultaneous use.  It knows how to keep everything straight.  ON THE OTHER HAND, if what you have is working, it's really hard to argue with success.

Comment: Well, it is working for now, I haven't experienced any kind of problems so far.
I'm just trying to learn the "right way", if you know what I mean.
Because I was lookijng up connection pooling usng aiosqlite, and i couldn't really find something.